# ArchLinux under Xen fails to see root fs after kernel upgrade to Linux-3.0

Tags: xen, linux-kernel, arch-linux

I bought a VPS but the hosting company doesn't have a prebuilt image for Arch Linux x64, so I have to install from ISO using VNC in SolusVM.

The installation works fine, the box (Xen Guest) is bootable, but after an upgrade (pacman -Suy) kernel26 gets replaced with linux-3.0 and stops booting.

The message is:

```
Root device /dev/disk/by-uuid/{uuid} doesn't exist. Attempting to create it.
ERROR: unable to determine major/minor number of root device '/dev/disk/by-uuid/{uuid}
```

Only `by-id` and `by-path` folders exist in `/dev/disk` if checked from emergency shell, and the only device is QEMU CD-ROM.

How do I fix it so linux-3.0 boots under Xen?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try editing your /etc/fstab file on the VM to point to the "/" partition directly (e.g. /dev/sda1 or whatever your disk is) instead of the uuid?

My only other thought is that this is some sort of udev and linux 3.0 issue.

If neither work. Could you post more details of your configuration, such as the Xen guest configuration file, the /etc/fstab, and the complete kernel boot messages.

Also with the added detail this is a fine question for the xen-users mailing list:

http://lists.xensource.com/mailman/listinfo/xen-users